# Listing / lstinline and line breaks

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I'm using \lstinline among other things for writing file names of my source files. For example

```
\lstinline{foofoo.pl}
```

Then, sometimes I have the problem that some lines containing this string are longer than others:

[image: example]

If I use something like that

```
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
}
```

The text will be breaked like

```
foofoo
.pl
```

But I only want

```
asdfljsfljadf foofoo.pl
```

with a correct length of the line or a line break before the whole text of lstinline, like

```
asdfljsfljadf
foofoo.pl
```

I hope that you understand my problem... ;)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for such paragraphs use

```
\begin{sloppypar}
... your paragraph with \lstinline...
\end{sloppypar}
```

Comment: isn't there an universal solution? because I'm writing my thesis with about 50-100 pages.. And I don't want to check in each paragraph, if there appears such a problem..

Comment: use as documentclass option `draft`   and it will be easy to see where are such problems.