# Line break inside lstinline?

Tags: listings

is there a way to define inside lstinline line breaks globally? I only found this solution [Listing / lstinline and line breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149521/listing-lstinline-and-line-breaks) where i should use

```
\begin{sloppypar}
... your paragraph with \lstinline...
\end{sloppypar}
```

But this question is two years old, maybe there is now a better solution to declare it in the preambel?

Comment: From what I know, there is no such option.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing, and this is among the top results, but no answer. Apparently, there now is a better option:
[Enforce a line-break inside \lstinline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/enforce-a-line-break-inside-lstinline)

```
\lstinline[breaklines=true]$...$
```

works for me. However, with very long stuff, i.e.

```
\lstinline[breaklines=true]$ffmpeg  -framerate 3 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -loglevel fatal -vcodec libx264 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune animation mymovietitle.mp4$
```

where no one would bother to make the code more readable in the first place (being one line, is the key quality of a bash one liner), it still can produce ugly stuff, so it's not the perfect solution.

[image]